# jQuery execution error with Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

Does anyone know why Safari doesn't execute the following script (It isn't a problem in Chrome or Firefox):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).on('click', '.person_details_select', function(event){
      alert('works');
   });
});
```

It isn't a problem with a css-selector by id only by CSS class.

Thx

Comment: Not sure if that would fix it, but I think the last `}` should be `});`

Comment: This is not possible: this code will 100% work in all Safari. Not solvable problem. Unless you prove it with a non-working demo.

Comment: unless its a css issue and element with class person_details_select has height 0 for example